# Loading ONI: Can’t create any node of the requested type

Tags: kinect, openni, openframeworks, nite

I am working on OpenFrameworks with the addon ofxOpenNI by gameoverhack.
I got the addon successfully running on my Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 with xCode 7.2.

For those of you who have previously used this addon, you must be knowing that there are several examples provided with the addon, including one with simple ONI recording. I had an old ONI file recorded on my linux system and I tried to run it on the OS X installation. I got the following errors:

> [notice ] ofxOpenNIDevice[1]: Starting ONI player:test.oni [verbose]
>   ofxOpenNIDevice[1]: Loading ONI: ../../../data/test.onistatus:Can't
>   create any node of the requested type!

And a blank screen appeared. Anyone knows a fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred due to the missing *config* folder in `$PROJECT_ROOT/bin/data`. I had included `ofxOpenNI` in an older project and therefore, the instruction where you have to replace your *bin* folder was missed.

This might be helpful to someone who faces the same issue in the future.